# Volume of a tilted cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, volume, riemann-integration

Suppose I have a tilted cylinder of length l inclined to the horizontal by an angle of $\theta$ then it's volume comes out to be same as that of a straight cylinder of height $l\sin\theta$.
I tried to find a formal proof for this online but all I got was vague analogies of a stack of coins and pile of discs.
Any proof using single variable calculus will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the coin/disc analogy? Just translate that analogy into the language of calculus, e.g. the "coins" have thickness $d \ell$ for example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri's_principle

Answer (score 0):

The Cavalieri's principle as suggested by Arthur is the good idea. I will hint an alternative: wlog suppose that the centers are along the line $z = x\sin\theta_0$. Do a change of coordinates transforming the tilted cylinder in a cylinder. Obviously, in the new coordinates $u,v,w$
$$u = \cdots$$
$$v = y,$$
$$w = z.$$